# Excel VBA copying multiple sheets from multiple files in a folder into multiple sheets in one file

Tags: excel, vba, file, merge, spreadsheet

I have been trying to find a quick solution to "merge" excel files, came across at least a dozen different codes, tried recording my own macro and modifying that (instead of a range of sheet names trying to select the lot etc.) none of worked anywhere near the way I wanted it to, most of them didn't work at all.

The context as follows:
I have a lot of files in a folder ("C:\Zoltan\TEST\"), most have multiple sheets. I want to copy

- all the sheets that DO NOT HAVE "Mailing" in the sheet name
- from all the files that DO NOT HAVE "Printing" in the file name
- into one file ("C:\Zoltan\TEST.xlsx") keeping the sheets separate as they are in the source files
- only if the sheet name already exist, I want to give it a date stamp (e.g. the sheet called "NTI UK (150)" from "E8795 NTI Mailing Order.XLSX" created on the 28th August 2105 to become "NTI UK (150) 20150828"

Below is as far as I got, which unfortunately doesn't seem to do anything. Currently I'm running the macro from the opened destination file (which is not much of an issue, I'm quite happy to have it that way). I'm also still missing the "Printing" exclusion (instead of the "Mailing" inclusion) in the FILE NAME and the whole date stamp bit, but those will be my next steps:

```
Sub CombineSheets()
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFname As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wSht As Worksheet

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sPath = "C:\Zoltan\TEST\"
ChDir sPath
sFname = "*Mailing*"
sFname = Dir(sPath & "\" & sFname & ".xl*", vbNormal)
Do Until sFname = ""
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(sFname)
    Windows(sFname).Activate
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If Not ws.Name Like "*Mailing*" Then ws.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        wbk.Close False
        sFname = Dir()
    Next
Loop
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I hope I've drawn up the problem in a clear and easy to understand way, but just to be on the safe side, if I did this manually it would be the following:

1. Open the TEST file
2. Open a source file that does not have the word
   "Printing" in the file name
3. Highlight all the sheets that do not
   have "Mailing" in the sheet name (these are just forms, not data
   sheets, I don't need them)
4. Right click and "Move or Copy", tick
   "Create a copy", select TEST.xlsx and select Sheet1
5. Close source file and move on to the next one

Please note, if the above is pure butchery, that is due to my lack of sufficient VBA skills. I tend to look at other people's codes, or record macros, take them apart and then try to make sense of them and put them back together the way I want them to work.

Where do I go wrong? Is there an easier way to code this? NB. I'd much rather copy entire sheets than highlighting ranges within sheets and place those ranges into new sheets in the destination file, like most codes (that I have come across) would do.

Many thankZ

Comment: You're calling `Dir()` and closing the source workbook in your inner loop through the sheets - you should move those lines to just before `Loop`

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the comment, I have moved the lines out of the loop, and it throws a run-time error saying that it can't find [...].xlsx file. I tried with sFname = Dir(sPath & sFname & ".xl*", vbNormal) as sPath already contains a backslash after TEST, but it just drops the same error message. The file it can't find is the first file in C:\Zoltan\TEST\ - is it changing directory somewhere and trying to find the file in another folder after getting its name?

Answer (score 0):

Is your code creating a copy of the sheets you find? You're not explaining exactly what is, or is not, happening. You do have your sFname = Dir() command in the wrong place... And I suggest just automatically setting the names rather than trying to see if a name exists...

The filename is easy enough, use the following within your do loop:

```
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(sFname)
Windows(sFname).Activate
For Each ws In Sheets
    If Not sFname Like "*printing*" Then
        If Not ws.Name Like "*Mailing*" Then
            ws.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name + Format(Now(), "yyyyMMdd-hhmm")
        End If
        wbk.Close
    End If
Next
sFname = Dir()
```

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't really clear: the code does nothing that is visible to the naked eye - I have not quite gotten to the point yet where I would run it and output every variable and try to make every step produce a visible result, I'll do that shortly. What do you mean by "automatically setting the names"?

Comment: By automatically setting the names I mean create the new sheet and immediately give it a unique name, as I have done in the internal If in my above code. It is a lot simpler than trying to determine if a sheet already exists with a specific name.

Comment: Sorry @PKatona, company is going through an acquisition which hasn't allowed me to return to this issue. It's still on the table, and will test solutions posted here and respond/vote etc as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

Some fixes:

```
Sub CombineSheets()

    Const sPath As String = "C:\Zoltan\TEST\"
    Dim sFname As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wSht As Worksheet

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'sPath already has a trailing \ - don't add another...
    sFname = Dir(sPath & "*Mailing*.xl*", vbNormal)

    Do Until sFname = ""

        'Dir only gives you the filename - use full path below
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFname)

        For Each wSht In wbk.WorkSheets
            If Not wSht.Name Like "*Mailing*" Then 
                wSht.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            End If
        Next
        'moved these lines out of the sheets loop
        wbk.Close False
        sFname = Dir()

    Loop

    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry @Tim Williams, company is going through an acquisition which hasn't allowed me to return to this issue. It's still on the table, and will test solutions posted here and respond/vote etc as soon as I can!